# VB Get Autonum values

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I use the first "Using" statement below to insert a row to a table called "Archives". This table has a primary key that is an autonum in an Access db. The second Using statement I use to retrieve the value for the autonum field, searching by the parameters that I just entered. While this works perfectly well, it just seems ugly. Is there a way to get the autonum field returned to me after the insert?  (BTW - I have deleted some code from between these two statements so if it looks a little strange, that may be why.

```
    Using myConn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
        myInsertCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Archives (ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain, ArchDate, ArchRoot, ArchStatus) 
        VALUES (@strArchUser, @strArchUserDomain, @dteArchDate, @strArchRoot, @strArchStatus);", myConn)
            myInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@strArchUser", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchUser
            myInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@strArchDomain", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchDomain
            myInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@dteArchDate", OleDbType.Date, 20).Value = dteArchDate
            myInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@strArchRoot", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strArchRoot
            myInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@strArchStatus", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchStatus
            myConn.Open()
            myInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

       Dim sql As String = "SELECT ArchID
       FROM Archives
       WHERE ArchUserName = @ArchUserName
       AND ArchUserDomain = @ArchUserDomain
       AND ArchDate = @ArchDate
       AND ArchRoot = @ArchRoot"

        Using myConn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
              command As New OleDbCommand(sql, myConn)
            With command.Parameters
                .Add("@ArchUserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchUser
                .Add("@ArchUserDomain", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchDomain
                .Add("@ArchDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = dteArchDate
                .Add("@ArchRoot", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchRoot
            End With

            myConn.Open()
            strArchID = "Arch" & CStr(command.ExecuteScalar())
            strDirectoryName = "Archive" & CStr(command.ExecuteScalar())
            ReturnCode = 0
        End Using
```

Comment: See `"SELECT @@Identity"`. You can keep `ExecuteScalar()`. Someone could ask *what for?*

Comment: You should not be calling `ExecuteScalar` twice to get the value. It should obviously be the same value both times so why execute the same query twice? Call `ExecuteScalar` once, assign the result to a variable and then use that variable multiple times. NEVER execute the same complex expression multiple times unless you expect a different result each time. A database query is one of the worst complex expression to do this with as it is so expensive.

Comment: Also, you should not be creating two separate connections. Create one connection, open it, execute the `INSERT` statement, execute the query to get the auto-generated ID and then close the connection.

Comment: Admit I've only done this via Enterprise Library, not straight ADO but can't see it not working.  Append SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NewID to the end of your insert command, then ExecuteScaler() will return you the id of the newly created record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @@Identity on the same connection immediately after the insert.

```
Private Function InsertArchiveRetrieveID(strArchUser As String, strArchDomain As String, dteArchDate As Date, strArchRoot As String, strArchStatus As String) As Integer
    Dim NewID As Integer
    Using myConn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
            myInsertCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Archives (ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain, ArchDate, ArchRoot, ArchStatus) 
                                                               VALUES (@strArchUser, @strArchUserDomain, @dteArchDate, @strArchRoot, @strArchStatus);", myConn)
        With myInsertCommand.Parameters
            .Add("@strArchUser", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchUser
            .Add("@strArchDomain", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchDomain
            .Add("@dteArchDate", OleDbType.Date, 20).Value = dteArchDate
            .Add("@strArchRoot", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strArchRoot
            .Add("@strArchStatus", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strArchStatus
        End With
        myConn.Open()
        myInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Using RetrieveNewIDCommand As New OleDbCommand("Select @@Identity From Archives,", myConn)
            NewID = CInt(RetrieveNewIDCommand.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return NewID
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NewID = InsertArchiveRetrieveID(txtUser.Text, txtDomain.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value, txtRoot.Text, txtStatus.Text)
    Dim strArchID = "Arch" & CStr(NewID)
    Dim strDirectoryName = "Archive" & CStr(NewID)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note: It's absolutely crucial that the connection remains open between the INSERT and the SELECT @@IDENTITY. Some programmers prefer to close the connection after each DB interaction. So do I and I fell into this trap. This is the exception where you have to remain the connection open. Otherwise you get nothing, which means 0.

Comment: @Aranxo Excellent point! See the first line of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I think it should be clear, but maybe someone misinterpretes this and thinks of a connection as the same DB which is defined by its connection string, and not as the same *opened* condition of this connection. So it wasn't meant to criticize you. :-)